# Firebase (FCM) Response messes up my Response

Tags: php, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending Web Push Notification via PHP cURL after my order successfully inserted into the database. After insertion, my return response is this:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "status": true,
    "message": "create-order-success",
    "data": {
        "order_id": 624
    }
}
```

But after FCM code, I'm getting a mixed response (firebase + mine) like:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 91xxxx99xxxx66xxxx6,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [{
        "message_id": "x:15xxxx39xxxx37xxxx60xxxxcfxxxxecx"
    }]
} {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "status": true,
    "message": "create-order-success",
    "data": {
        "order_id": 624
    }
}
```

And due to this response, my app crashes. Is there any way I can edit this response or didn't get this response from Firebase?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you fix this? @MAK

Answer (score 0):

setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to TRUE in curl_setopt worked for me.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```